# configure httpd.conf to support same IP and different PATH ,with one default page

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I am configure the httpd.conf to support same IP addr and different virtualHost.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/
    ServerName AA    </VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerPath /var/www/
    ServerName BB
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, I can access the webpage by

```
http://192.168.20.100/AA
```

and

```
http://192.168.20.100/BB
```

This is almost done, but I need the final step.If the user access the IP address, I want to show them the default AA, that is when user access `http://192.168.20.100/` , the content of `http://192.168.20.100/AA` will be showed.
I give it a lot of tries, but none works. The following ways i have tried:
1) configure the global DocumentRoot in httpd.conf
2) set the serverName to empty to "/"

Have anyone met the same situation?

Comment: try adding the IP address to the first <virtualhost *:80> block so it reads <VirtualHost *:80 192.168.20.100>. It appears to work for me, but I've a none standard setup locally so can't test thoroughly.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I use the built-in httpd of redhat [root@localhost batsDoc]# httpd -v Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) Server built: Dec 5 2012 04:03:01  If I access the http://192.168.20.100, it will give me the redhat built in welcome page.